# Use the results of an sql query to run in a second SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to se the results of a sql query in a Proc, for example I'm looking to automate Grant's on Roles to certain tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'GRANT SELECT ON '|| TABLE_NAME ||' TO BI_PUBLISHED_ACCESS;'
FROM BI.dd_tables
WHERE PUBLISHED = 'Y';

Output:-
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE1 TO BI_PUBLISHED_ACCESS;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE2 TO BI_PUBLISHED_ACCESS;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE3 TO BI_PUBLISHED_ACCESS;
AND SO ON
```

I then copy & paste the output back into the worksheet & run the full script to grant select on all of my published table to the BI_PUBLISHED_ACCESS Roll.

My process works but it is a very manual operation. My question is can I use the output of one query to run another one?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement.

So, the solution will looks like:

```
BEGIN
for grant_statement in
  (SELECT DISTINCT 'GRANT SELECT ON '|| TABLE_NAME ||' TO BI_PUBLISHED_ACCESS;'
   FROM BI.dd_tables
   WHERE PUBLISHED = 'Y')
   LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE grant_statement;
   END LOOP;
END;
```